# Removing vertical white space between divs, especially after hitting a breakpoint

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, responsive-design

I'm working on a responsive page design at the moment and I'm running into an issue with white-space between the divs, especially after hitting breakpoints.

```css
body, html {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.header {
  padding-top: 5px;
  background-color: red;
  width: 100%;
}
.sub-header {
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 0px;
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 100%;
}
.main-content {
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: blue;
  width: 100%;
}
.footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: green;
  width: 100%;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 320px) {
  .sub-header {
    display: none;
  }
}
}
```

```html
<div class="header">Header
  <div class="sub-header">Sub-Header</div>
</div>
<div class="main-content">Auto adjust size</div>
I want to have the blue div take up the remaining         space in this white space, as well as after the sub-header is removed at the break point.
<div class="footer">footer</div>
```

Here's a quick mock up of what I'm experiencing: http://jsfiddle.net/gaych7vp/6/

I understand what I have to do in order to make it take up the remainder of the white space before it hits a breakpoint (I'm assuming just tweaking the height values), but how would I go about making the blue div take up the remaining white space that gets created when the yellow div gets hidden after hitting the breakpoint?

I'm still really new to javascript but from other answers I've read it could be done by creation a function that finds the height of the browser and then subtracts it from the other divs.  Is that possible and if so, how could I accomplish that?

Comment: do you want to make main-content bigger to remote white space ?

Comment: @NullPoiиteя, there is an input box in the footer that utilizes ajax to put content in the "main content" div.  I just need to have the main content div take up the entirety of the space between the header, second div, and footer.

Answer (score 1):

Use `position:absolute` with different `top` values

```
.main-content {
    position:absolute;
    top:51px;
    bottom:0px;
}
```

and

```
@media screen and (max-width: 320px) {
    .main-content {
        top: 23px;
    }
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gaych7vp/7/)

Another approach is using `display:table` and `display:table-row`

```
body, html{
    width:100%;
    height: 100%;
}
body{
    display:table;
}
.main-content {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display:table-row;
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gaych7vp/9/)

[Make a div fill the height of the remaining screen space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/90178/make-a-div-fill-the-height-of-the-remaining-screen-space)

Comment: So as I mentioned above, there is an input box in the footer that utilizes ajax to put content in the "main content" div. I just need to have the main content div take up the entirety of the space between the header, second div, and footer.  I've tried your methods and it's still acting a bit wonky.  Is there anything else you could recommend?

Comment: @st565, was the second way(table and table-row) wonky also?

Comment: unfortunately yes.  When I made a new index file and tried the table method without any content it worked perfectly.  However, once I added in the content from my original index file, it started to not auto adjust in height or width.  I'm going to play around with it a bit more to see if I an fix it though.  Thanks for your help in the meantime!

Answer (score 0):

You can use calc on the `.main-content` div to calculate the size, but you would need to set the heights of the header, footer, and subheader divs.  Seems to me though you could just give the body a background color of blue, and achieve the same thing?

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
@media screen and (max-width: 320px) {
    .sub-header {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

to

```
@media screen and (max-width: 320px) {
    .sub-header {
        visibility: hidden;
    }
}
```

I think this is what you meant. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gaych7vp/8/).

Answer (score 0):

There's no need for a JavaScript solution here.

The white area is caused because you are using `position: absolute` to force the footer to the bottom of the window, regardless of the content.

This isn't the normal way to achieve this, you'll run into issues later on when you do add content to your `main-content` div. You'll find that the footer will be positioned over this content (this will also happen if you shrink the window vertically).

I think what you'd like to do, is give the `main-content` div a `min-height:`, this way, the page won't collapse and look terrible if there is little content, but it will stretch naturally when more content is added.

You can also and remove the `position: absolute` from the `footer` div.

Here is a demonstration:
http://jsfiddle.net/t46aopas/

** UPDATE **

If you'd like a dynamic solution, I've created a heavily annotated JavaScript example here: http://jsfiddle.net/nahgdkaw/

(I included lots of comments since you said you were new to JavaScript ;) )

That should hopefully help you along the way a little.

Be aware that if the content inside the `.main-content` div is larger than the `.main-content` div area, the div will NOT expand to accommodate it.

You can however use the code provided and add in an `if` statement to, before resizing the `.main-content` div, check if the `.main-content` content
is larger than the available area (you may need to add a wrapper div around the `.main-content` content). If so, then resize the `.main-content` div to match the `.main-content` content height (otherwise, perform the resize as it currently is).

(Also, I strongly advise against using HTML tables for anything other than tabular data)

Answer (score 0):

I edited my original answer but don't have the reputation points necessary to add a comment to notify you. I'll remove this answer after you've seen my updated answer above.